# Inserting into std::map using struct fails with constructor error

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I have the following...

```
struct MessageLetter{
  char letter;
  int count;
  MessageLetter(char letter, int freq)
  : letter(letter), count(freq)
  {}
};
...
std::map<char, MessageLetter> lList;
...
MessageLetter m = MessageLetter(letter,1);
lList[letter] = m;
```

When I try to compile I get...

```
no matching constructor for initialization of 'MessageLetter'
            ::new ((void*)__p) _Tp();
```

Gotta be something easy anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
lList[letter] = m;
```

This line actually defaultly constructs a `MessageLetter` then returns it by reference, you then assign m to it, calling `operator=`.

This means that `MessageLetter` requires a defualt constructor, like so:

```
MessageLetter() {}
```

or with C++11:

```
MessageLetter()=default;
```

if you don't intend to actually do anything in it.

You can also get away without having to defaultly construct using `std::map::insert`

```
lList.insert(std::make_pair(letter), m));
```

or emplace with c++11:

```
lList.emplace(letter, { letter, 1 });
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: I am not sure your emplace example is actually correct. I would have expected `list.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(letter), std::forward_as_tuple(letter, 1));`

Answer (score 1):

The `operator[]` for an `std::map` requires that the mapped type be default-constructible (since it first default constructs a new element, then returns a reference to it, and you then *assign* to that). This isn't the case for you. You should use `insert` or `emplace` instead:

```
lList.insert(std::make_pair(letter, MessageLetter(letter, 1)));

// or

lList.emplace(letter, MessageLetter(letter, 1));
```

Both functions return information about whether the insertion was possible (the key may already have existed) and location of the element with the given key.

Comment: This works too thanks but I think the next one is a little more detailed so I am accepting it.